Falstad Circuit Simulator: Issues Simulating a Peak Detector
I was attempting to simulate a peak detector circuit and noticed that when the input to the peak detector is a square wave, the simulator goes a little nuts and the voltage across the capacitor ends up being a voltage much higher than the voltage of the input pulse.  The image below shows the output I'm describing:

However, this only seems to happen with square wave/pulse inputs, other signals don't seem to create this problem. Has anyone else seen this issue? If so, why's this happening, and is there a way around it?

The trick here is not to use falsenad but grab a decent piece of engineering simulation software and use it. Both ways are free but one way makes total sense and, the other way is a suitable toy for a child.

Put a 10mOhm resistor in series with your ideal diode. You need some form of current limiting so the simulation can "converge". For more accurate (and realistic results), use a SPICE simulator. LTSpice would be a good start.

Thank you for the response! I actually had tried this earlier, in conjunction with changing the diode to a "real" 1n4004 model; still seeing the same issue though. If I remove the diode and only have the series resistance, the cap rises to the expected value, so I do agree that it's a diode model quirk.

@user24331180 The Falstad "simulator" is a bit gimmicky and I would never use it for modeling real circuits. It's great for "simple, well-behaved" especially linear circuits, and it has the cute current graphics. But it fails with step responses and any sort of discontinuities. Plus, the Falstad models are dubious. Run the same simulation on Linear Tech or TI's simulator, and you will see what I'm talking about.

Falstad simulator is a fairly basic [ah, but see below!] numerical solving engine.  "Basic" is relative here, mind: it's capable of running arbitrary circuits, no small feat especially for a casual in-browser program; but nonlinear circuits (e.g. those involving diodes, transistors, etc.) can be endlessly complex, and the methods to solve or approximate them, equally so.
It uses, I believe, a fixed timestep and Euler integration.  This is convenient as an answer is always possible -- the solution doesn't tend to bog down on rapid changes -- but so too, the results around rapid changes need not be very representative.
It might be a modified method, as plain Euler or trapezoidal integration (or a few other roughly-similar methods) tend to produce oscillatory output around sudden changes, and I don't recall it producing such output (but, I haven't exactly used it extensively).  These results are characteristic as they alternate per timestep: this usually ends up drawn as a triangular wave oscillation; they can be ignored as numerical artifacts, not physical oscillation.
In this case, it matters whether the PULSE source occurs in one time step, or ramps smoothly over many steps.  The simulator can still produce an answer in the former case -- but don't be surprised if it's unrealistic.
In a SPICE engine, we only have continuous sources -- at least piecewise continuous, but preferably C1 or higher (i.e. at least 1 continuous derivative), and similarly the functions used to model components.  In brief, a numerical solver performs integration by repeated differentiation: the derivative tells the slope of the function, and by adding that increment multiplied by the timestep, we extrapolate the function, bit by bit.  This doesn't work if the derivative is unrealistic, or nonexistent -- a solver may still be able to come up with an answer in that case (for example, a smooth derivative might be approximated by averaging points taken around a sudden change), but don't be surprised if the results become unrealistic.

Further reading: ah, here we go, straight to the source.  Literally.  You may like to see the source of CircuitJS: 
https://github.com/sharpie7/circuitjs1/tree/master
The engine is discussed briefly here, and the option of backward Euler or trapezoidal methods (which are first-order so don't need higher derivatives) is mentioned: 
https://github.com/sharpie7/circuitjs1/blob/master/INTERNALS.md
The core functions appear to be here, 
https://github.com/sharpie7/circuitjs1/blob/master/src/com/lushprojects/circuitjs1/client/CirSim.java 
in particular runCircuit() seems to be the most interesting part.  I see variable timestepping, in fact; very cool.
So there is a fixed timestep, I think, given by the animation speed, or else available CPU power, but they are also sub-stepping in order to approach convergence more cautiously -- rather than powering through a big step change and producing garbage (or worse, inf or NaNs..!).
The diode, 
https://github.com/sharpie7/circuitjs1/blob/master/src/com/lushprojects/circuitjs1/client/Diode.java 
and capacitor, 
https://github.com/sharpie7/circuitjs1/blob/master/src/com/lushprojects/circuitjs1/client/CapacitorElm.java 
show how the device equations, and backwards Euler or trapezoidal integration, are implemented.
Note that it's written in Java (as the original was: the Falstad simulation section was originally a collection Java applets that ran in the browser; this was years and years ago!), and trans-piled to JS with GWT.
I haven't seen the full core of (e.g. Berkeley 3f5) SPICE myself, but what I understand from documentation is, they're doing a good bit of it here already.  SPICE uses LU decomposition and pivoting to optimize matrix inversions, and supports trapezoidal integration (of note, higher-order methods (of the Runge-Kutta family I believe) are also supported, and generally produce better-behaved results for practical nonlinear circuits).
